# Clicking in the top corners of my webpage causes the flex boxes to misbehave

Tags: javascript, html, flexbox

I have been making a simple page using flexboxes that should expand one flex box to the majority of the page on a click. However, the page will occasionally make the sizes of all of the flexboxes equal (see the below picture). I've only notices it when I click in the corners of the page on the yellow or blue sections. Does anyone have an idea of what is going on?

[image: a picture of the issue]

Edit: Added relevant code and removed JS Bin links

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link href="/stylesheets/flex.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="yel" class="page selected">
      <h2>Home
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="green" class="page">
      <h2>About Me
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="red" class="page">
      <h2>Portfolio
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="blue" class="page">
      <h2>Playground
      </h2>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row;
}
.selected {
  min-width: 90%;
}
#red {
  background-color: #f00;
}
#yel {
  background-color: #ff0;
}
#green {
  background-color: #008000;
}
#blue {
  background-color: #00f;
}
.page {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 750ms;
}
.page h2 {
  font: 20px Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif bold;
  color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin: 5px;
}
.content {
  margin: 10% auto auto auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

JS

```
var $ = function(sel, e) {return (e || document).querySelector(sel)};
var $$ = function(sel, e) {return (e || document).querySelectorAll(sel)};

var boxes = $$('.page');
var links = $$('.nav');
var flexTransitionTo = function flexTransitionTo(el) {
  if(!el.classList.contains('selected')) {
    $('.selected').classList.remove('selected');
    el.classList.add('selected');
  }
};

for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
  var el;
  boxes[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    el = event.target;
    flexTransitionTo(el);
  });
}

for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  var el;
  var pageEl;

  links[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    el = event.target;
    pageEl = $(el.dataset.page); //should get the page I want

    flexTransitionTo(pageEl);
  });
}
```

Comment: What browsers and what versions?

Comment: @Andrew Marshall Most recent version of Chrome (28). I am only using the webkit prefixes in the JS Bin, so only Chrome will show the webpage properly.

Comment: Cannot reproduce (Chrome 28).

Comment: It seems to be happening when you click in the top part of one of the sections, and then click to expand another. I tried again, and it happened when I clicked the red and then the green a few times in a row.

Comment: Placing relevant code here will let your question stay useful for future visitors when JSBin goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you the why, but I can't give you the fix (my JavaScript-fu is weak).  The problem is that when you click on the h2 element (or probably any other descendant of the page element), it is intercepting the click event and *it* has the *selected* class applied to it.  Because the *selected* class is removed from all page elements, none of them are set to *selected*.